# Is it possible to export publishing queue entries?

Tags: publishing, 2009

Is it possible to export entries in the publishing queue using the content management explorer (CME) in Tridion 2009 SP1?  I'd like to view this in Excel so that I can manipulate the data and use it for tracking purposes.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to use the old Publishing Queue manager [PowerTool](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx) to achieve this (but you may need to copy/paste the output end HTML). Otherwise you may have to write your own script to achieve this.

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Unfortunately, we won't be able to install the Powertools on a production environment in time.  It looks like I'll need to scrape the HTML.

Comment: I don't recommend scraping the HTML. Just use the TOM/TDSE API to access the pub queue entries.

Comment: Nick - Unfortunately, I don't have access to the box to implement a server side solution (unless one can do this remotely - let me know if this is possible).

Comment: It is possible with the Business Connector and the XML API - not simple, but worth posting a question here...

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy to write a console program or custom page using the TOM API (TDSE) that gives access to the publishing queue. Just look at the API documentation.  The easies thing to do is output the queue entries in CSV format either straight to a file, or Console.WriteLine(my_csv_formatted_line) and pipe it to a file, e.g. MyPubQueueOutputProgram.exe > my_queue_output.csv.